# Database connection doesn't work locally but works on server?

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, server, pgadmin-4

I want to do modifications on my .Net Core API but i'm facing issue when I want to do my request, I always have an error

> An error occurred using the connection to database 'databaseName' on server 'tcp://serverName:5432'
>
> An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'ProjectName.Models.DBContextName'

The problem if when I try to run it locally it doesn't work but it works on server.

I don't know why it doesn't work, I just know that it was working perfectly before our update of PgAdmin.

Someone have any solution ?

Comment: Could you describe your problem a bit better?  Any screenshots to share?  What do you mean by "run it locally"?  Do you mean if you run both your c# program and database on your laptop, it's fine, but when you run your c# program on your laptop, connecting to remote database, you get error?  And how is all this related to pgadmin?

Comment: @richyen I just have an error 500, I see the error in the console when I try to run the project locally. I wanted to say when I run my program on my laptop with a remote connection for my database I get this errors.

For pgadmin I say that because before the update of pgadmin I have no error and after it I have the error, and also in my laptop I have a pgadmin v3 (the same version before the update of the server) and if I want to connect to a database I have no error I have this error only if I have to connect to my remote database.